# How to calculate SHA-256 checksum of S3 file content in memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, sha256, sophoslabs-intelix

I'm looking to compute the sha256 checksum of an image file located in S3 without writing it to disk.

I have tried the code below:

```
  const data = (
    await getS3().getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileName }).promise()
  ).Body.toString('utf-8');

  logger.info(`File data: ${data}`);
  const sha256 = createHash('sha256');
  sha256.update(data);
  const hex = sha256.digest('hex');
  logger.info(`SHA256 HEX: ${hex}`);
```

The value of `hex` matches the same as other browser based tools (e.g. https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256_checksum.html) if I use a basic .txt file, but when I use an image file (.png), I am getting a different value. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

I also tried using

```
const data = (
    await getS3().getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileName }).promise()
  ).Body.toString('binary');
```

still the sha256 is different.

I think maybe I need to use S3.getObject(params).createReadStream() but I don't know why that would make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually got the solution here by using a read stream instead of the promise version of getObject:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const hash = createHash('sha256');
    const stream = S3.getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileName }).createReadStream();

    stream.on('data', (d) => hash.update(d));
    stream.on('end', () => {
      const digest = hash.digest('hex');
      logger.debug(`SHA256: [${digest}]`);
      resolve(digest);
    });
    stream.on('error', reject);
  });
```

Comment: Hi Cole, thanks for answering your question here. If it still helps there is an example implementation on GitHub - https://github.com/sophoslabs/intelix-lambda-example/blob/master/resources/intelix_file_check.py